# Se puede sumar directamente en una consulta mysql?

Tags: mysql

Quisiera saber si existe la posibilidad de al actualizar un campo en mysql, si se puede consultar lo que había previamente para sumar la nueva cantidad.

ósea tengo un campo de unidades que tiene un valor XX y quiero sumarle una nueva cantidad. Normalmente hago primero una consulta para ver ese valor y luego en un update sumo el valor antiguo con el nuevo.

¿se puede simplificar?

el código que suelo usar es este:

```
 $CExisteArti = Consulta_Dinamica("Simple","*","Stock","`idarticulo` = '".$CExisteEan["idcosa"]."' AND `almacen` = '".$_POST['AValmacen']."' AND `idEan` = '".$CExisteEan["id"]."' ");

 $Nstock = $CExisteArti["stock"] + $_POST["AVcantidad"];

 $ModStock = Actualizar_Datos("Stock" , "`stock` = '$Nstock' ","idarticulo","".$CExisteEan["idcosa"].""," AND `almacen` = '".$_POST['AValmacen']."' ");
```

No es que sea vital hacerlo en una única consulta, es simplemente por simplificar y añadir conocimientos.

Mil gracias a todos.

Comment: Es posible. Sería algo así: `UPDATE tabla SET columna = columna + valor WHERE id = criterio` El dato `valor` debe ser un entero. También se recomienda usar consultas preparadas para este tipo de consultas. Y **no olvides el WHERE**, de lo contrario te actualizaría los valores de todas las filas a no ser que sea eso lo que quieres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es posible sumar en un **UPDATE** sin el **SELECT** previo, sería algo así:

```
UPDATE Inventario SET Stock = Stock + "Nueva cantidad"
```